# Failed to instantiate module myApp but i have declared it

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have the following jsfiddle and i'm not sure what's wrong with it?

Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1988/8kx0s953/7/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">    
  <points></points>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pointstemplate">
      rgrgerg
  </script>
</div>

angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .component('points', {
    templateUrl: 'pointstemplate',
    controllerAs: 'viewModel',
    controller: function(){
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder the resources so that jQuery is before angular.min.js